# how to fix the order of the buttons in SWT?

Tags: java, swt

I have scroller with 2 buttons

How i can set that the order of the buttons will be in the same raw and not each control : button scroller and button will be in different row

```
    fComposite= new Composite(composite, SWT.RIGHT_TO_LEFT);
    GridData layoutData= new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.RIGHT_TO_LEFT, true, false);
    fComposite.setLayoutData(layoutData);
    layout= new GridLayout(1, false);
    layout.marginHeight= 0;
    layout.marginWidth= 0;
    layout.horizontalSpacing= 0;
    layout.verticalSpacing= 0;

    fComposite.setLayout(layout);

    Display display = parent.getDisplay();
    Shell shell = parent.getShell(); 
    Button button = new Button(fComposite, SWT.LEFT);
    button.setText("Two"); //$NON-NLS-1$
    button.setImage(display.getSystemImage(ICON_1));    

    final Scale scale = new Scale (fComposite, SWT.BORDER);
    Rectangle clientArea = fComposite.getClientArea ();
    scale.setBounds (clientArea.x, clientArea.y, 200, 64);
    scale.setMaximum (5);
    scale.setPageIncrement (1);
    scale.setSelection(5);

    Button rButton = new Button(fComposite, SWT.RIGHT);
    rButton.setText("Two"); //$NON-NLS-1$
    rButton.setImage(display.getSystemImage(ICON_2));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you read the article about SWT layouts that I posted in one of your other questions?

The `Display` and `Shell` are the first things to create. After that you can add things to the `shell`.

Your problem is based on the fact, that you created a `GridLayout` with just one column. Thus all widgets are below each other.

```
layout= new GridLayout(1, false);
```

The first parameter is the number of columns. Set it to 3 for three columns.

Please read the documentation of the layout and the article: [Understanding layouts in SWT](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/article.php?file=Article-Understanding-Layouts/index.html) before asking further questions. It will definitely help you.